# CommandError: No fixture named 'fixture' found

Tags: python, django, django-fixtures

I'm trying to use `loaddata` to load some fixtures into a Django 2.2.10 project. According to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#loaddata), the command should look like this:

```
python manage.py loaddata fixture app/fixtures/*.json
```

However, when I run this command I get the following error:

```
CommandError: No fixture named 'fixture' found.
```

I figured the word "fixture" was being interpreted as a path to the fixture, so I removed it and it worked:

```
python manage.py loaddata app/fixtures/*.json
```

I still find it weird though that the documentation tells me to do something that doesn't work. Am I missing something? I'm worried that I might have something wrong in my setup that is going to come back to haunt me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

to run fixtures in **django**. you should  follow this syntax:

**`python manage.py loaddata fixture_name`**

not  :

**`python manage.py loaddata fixture fixture_name`**

In your case you should run  `python manage.py loaddata app/fixtures/*.json`

instead of `python manage.py loaddata fixture app/fixtures/*.json` because  **fixture** here   will be treated as **fixture_name and it is not**  .

Comment: That's what I'm inclined to believe as well. But that means the documentation is wrong (both online and via command line), which is a bit surprising. I will post a ticket in the Django project or maybe even make a PR.

Comment: yeah they didn't make it clear it should be like this in the docs : `django-admin loaddata fixture [--options]` not like this `django-admin loaddata fixture [fixture ...]`